# file accessing issue in Nodejs and trouble shoot while displaying json content

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am using Expressjs and nodejs for accessing file and through that I am sending response to Angularjs. I am using `json` data to display the content in by browser. when I run the server, port is not displaying any message.

ExpressJS:

```
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./config');
var jsonserver = require('json-server');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/contact', function(req,res) {
    if (res.sendFile(path.normalize(__dirname + '/public/contact.json'))) {
        console.log('Request is received');     
    } else {
        console.log('Error');
    } 
});
```

I don't where I Have gone wrong. Please let me know my mistake . Any help/advise greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using `path.normalize()` correctly? try this `if (res.sendFile(path.normalize( '/public/contact.json')) !== 'undefined')`

Comment: Alright and should I include the normalize package or not ?

Comment: I got error stating that path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile @SatishPatel

Comment: you need to do this `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/contact.json')`

Comment: @SatishPatel. Well i debugged my code and every thing is working well. But the problem is my data is not  getting displayed in browser. Moreover i am getting the response properly